# Prove that $v(y',z') > v(y,z)$ if $y' > y$

Tags: number-theory

> For any positive $x_0$, three sequences $\{x_n\},\{y_n\},$ and $\{z_n\}$ are defined as follows:
>
> $\quad$ (i) $y_0 = 4$ and $z_0 = 1$;
>
> $\quad$ (ii) if $x_n$ is even for $n \geq 0, x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2}, 
> y_{n+1} = 2y_n,$ and $z_{n+1} = z_n$.
>
> $\quad$ (iii) if $x_n$ is odd for $n \geq 0, x_{n+1} = x_n-\frac{y_n}{2}-z_n, y_{n+1} = y_n,$ and $z_{n+1} = y_n+z_n$.
>
> Define $v(y_{n-1},z_{n-1}) = x_0$ where $x_n = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$. Prove that $v(y',z') > v(y,z)$ if $y' > y$ and $v(y,z') > v(y,z)$ if $z' > z$.

I didn't see how to prove this since we have two conditions for the function and so it is hard to manage how large $x_0$ gets. How can we use the information to prove the result?

Comment: What does this mean: "Define $\nu(y_{n-1},z_{n-1})=x_0$"?

Comment: This means that for example, if we have $v(2,3)$, then $2 = y_{n-1}$ and $3  =z_{n-1}$ and $v(2,3) = x_0$.